# Can't run an own script in an own Google Sheet - ""App isn't verified" appears

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-cloud-platform, google-api

In my own Google account i'm using a Google Sheets `gs`-script to check URLs through PageSpeed API. In the Cloud Console i enabled this API and created an API key under /credentials/.

After adding an API key to the script and running it i firstly forced to authentificate me (despite i'm logged into my account). After authentification i get the `App isn't verified` screen without `advanced` link, so i even have no possibility to run it with limitations.

The same issue appears, if i create a Google Sheets document in *another* Google account, add the script to it, than share this document with *my* Google account and create a copy from it.

The issue happens independently of which URLs i want to test with my script - those from website, where i'm the validated owner, or those which don't belong to me.

In my opinion this issue is something new: earlier this year i was copying Google Sheets with scripts from other accounts into my, and all scripts were running like a charm.

What should i do to run my script in my Google Sheets document?

If it could be important, here is the script for PageSpeed test:

```
//@OnlyCurrentDoc

/**
 * Returns Mobile Speed & Optimization and Desktop Speed & Optimization values in six adjacent columns
 * by Cagri Sarigoz
 */
function checkAll(Url) {


    var key = "myAPI";
    var serviceUrlMobile = "https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v4/runPagespeed?url=" + Url + "&strategy=mobile&key=" + key;
    var serviceUrlDesktop = "https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v4/runPagespeed?url=" + Url + "&strategy=desktop&key=" + key;
    //    var serviceUrlMobileFriendliness = "https://searchconsole.googleapis.com/v1/urlTestingTools/mobileFriendlyTest:run?fields=mobileFriendliness&key="+key;
    //    var formDataMobileFriendliness = {'url':Url};
    //    var optionsMobileFriendliness = {
    //     'method' : 'post',
    //     'payload' : formDataMobileFriendliness
    //    };
    var array = [];

    var responseMobile = UrlFetchApp.fetch(serviceUrlMobile);

    if (responseMobile.getResponseCode() == 200) {
        var contentMobile = JSON.parse(responseMobile.getContentText());

        if ((contentMobile != null) && (contentMobile["ruleGroups"] != null)) {
            if (contentMobile["responseCode"] == 200) {
                var optimizationScoreMobile = contentMobile["ruleGroups"]["SPEED"]["score"];
                if ("metrics" in contentMobile["loadingExperience"]) {
                    var avgFCPMobile = ((contentMobile["loadingExperience"]["metrics"]["FIRST_CONTENTFUL_PAINT_MS"]["median"]) / 1000).toFixed(1).toString() + " (" + contentMobile["loadingExperience"]["metrics"]["FIRST_CONTENTFUL_PAINT_MS"]["category"] + ")";
                    var avgDCLMobile = ((contentMobile["loadingExperience"]["metrics"]["DOM_CONTENT_LOADED_EVENT_FIRED_MS"]["median"]) / 1000).toFixed(1).toString() + " (" + contentMobile["loadingExperience"]["metrics"]["DOM_CONTENT_LOADED_EVENT_FIRED_MS"]["category"] + ")";
                } else {
                    var avgFCPMobile = "Unavailable";
                    var avgDCLMobile = "Unavailable";
                }
            } else {
                var optimizationScoreMobile = "An error occured";
                var avgFCPMobile = "An error occured";
                var avgDCLMobile = "An error occured";

            }
        }
    }

    var responseDesktop = UrlFetchApp.fetch(serviceUrlDesktop);

    if (responseDesktop.getResponseCode() == 200) {
        var contentDesktop = JSON.parse(responseDesktop.getContentText());

        if ((contentDesktop != null) && (contentDesktop["ruleGroups"] != null)) {
            if (contentDesktop["responseCode"] == 200) {
                var optimizationScoreDesktop = contentDesktop["ruleGroups"]["SPEED"]["score"];
                if ("metrics" in contentDesktop["loadingExperience"]) {
                    var avgFCPDesktop = ((contentDesktop["loadingExperience"]["metrics"]["FIRST_CONTENTFUL_PAINT_MS"]["median"]) / 1000).toFixed(1).toString() + " (" + contentDesktop["loadingExperience"]["metrics"]["FIRST_CONTENTFUL_PAINT_MS"]["category"] + ")";
                    var avgDCLDesktop = ((contentDesktop["loadingExperience"]["metrics"]["DOM_CONTENT_LOADED_EVENT_FIRED_MS"]["median"]) / 1000).toFixed(1).toString() + " (" + contentDesktop["loadingExperience"]["metrics"]["DOM_CONTENT_LOADED_EVENT_FIRED_MS"]["category"] + ")";
                } else {
                    var avgFCPDesktop = "Unavailable";
                    var avgDCLDesktop = "Unavailable";
                }
            } else {
                var optimizationScoreDesktop = "An error occured";
                var avgFCPDesktop = "An error occured";
                var avgDCLDesktop = "An error occured";

            }
        }
    }

    //    var responseMobileFriendliness = UrlFetchApp.fetch(serviceUrlMobileFriendliness, optionsMobileFriendliness);
    //    var contentMobileFriendliness = JSON.parse(responseMobileFriendliness.getContentText());
    //      
    //      if ( (contentMobileFriendliness != null) && (contentMobileFriendliness["mobileFriendliness"] != null) )
    //      {
    //        var mobileFriendliness = contentMobileFriendliness["mobileFriendliness"];
    //      }
    //      else
    //        {
    //          var mobileFriendliness = "An error occured";
    //        }

    var currentDate = new Date().toJSON().slice(0, 10).replace(/-/g, '/');

    array.push([avgFCPMobile, avgDCLMobile, optimizationScoreMobile, avgFCPDesktop, avgDCLDesktop, optimizationScoreDesktop, currentDate]);
    Utilities.sleep(1000);
    return array;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to go through the [verification process](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7454865?hl=en). This is not new and has been around for a number of years now. Google will check your application to ensure that it follows their guidelines before you will be considered to be safe.

You can start the verification by submitting this [form](https://support.google.com/code/contact/oauth_app_verification) but before it is recommended to follow steps [here](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7454865)

Comment: Earlier, but for a long time, there was a usual way to share Google Spreadsheets, even those containing scripts: the author notified users: "To use this spreadsheet open and copy it into your own account". Once it was done any copied spreadsheet was directly working. Can you explain please: is this way doesn't work anymore? And own spreadsheets, even with scripts have never forced me to authentificate. You mean "a number of years"? I copied a spreadsheets with script from another developer two weeks ago and it doesn't forced any additional authentification - what could be there be different?

Comment: There’s no work around here if you run scripts with scopes that require authentication then you have To authenticate. Get used to it.